# Paging in the tags badges

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, pagination

When you go to [the tags badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) you get a **FULL** list with all the tags badges people got, in Stack overflow, this list has <s>thousands of</s>  **1747** lines.

The page loading is very slow, and the page is gigantic, shouldn't be there paging like in every other place in the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: It's not thousands, it's only 1747!

Comment: Also, why not only show the ones that the user is active in?

Comment: @BenBrocka. My bad... How can you tell?! You probably counted them...

Comment: Chrome's Ctrl+F is wonderful

Comment: @BenBrocka.. Nice move. :) I fixed the horrible mistake.